# Oracle intermittent performance problem

Tags: oracle, performance

I have some complex queries that are usually fast (< 1 sec), but occasionally slow (> 10 sec, even minutes).

How do I track this down or identify what condition is causing it?

One theory was caching - perhaps the query is fast when the blocks cached in memory.  I tried flushing both the shared pool and the buffer cache ("alter system flush buffer_cache") but the query is still fast after doing that.

Is there a way to nail down precisely what was going on during a specific execution that was bad, and which part of query execution took the longest?

Comment: Is the query itself "complex"? If it is, try also flushing the shared pool to force a parse on top of the  data block I/O.

Comment: As one of the possible solutions - configure tiny recycle pool and assign tables used in SQL to it.

Comment: Just flushing the buffer cache may not help if the OS also has the blocks cached. The only 100% way of doing this is a machine reboot. Even that may not work if you're connected to a SAN with a separate cache.

Comment: You can flush OS cache on linux. "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches". Also if you are using direct IO (filesystemio_options=setall) or ASM or RAW devices OS is not caching Oracle blocks.

Comment: Yes the query is "complex" - I flushed the shared pool as well.  It still runs fast (0.5 sec or less) after flushing shared pool and cache.  Yet randomly it will take 10+ sec or even a few minutes, and I can't figure out why.  Disk reads are not totally insane - 2000 blocks at most.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using and are you licensed to use the diagnostic and tuning packs?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production - I believe we have licenses for all of the above

Answer (score 1):

As you're on 11gR2 and suitably licensed (make sure you check!), I would recommend taking a look at the SQL monitor. This gives a detailed breakdown of all SQL statements that took more ~5s to execute in the past 24 hours.

Using this, you can see the duration of each step in the execution plan, along with I/O and wait details. This will enable you to see why it's taking so long.

The quick SQL executions won't appear by default, but you can add the `/*+ MONITOR */` hint to force them in.

You can get a graphical view of the plan using Enterprise Manager or SQL developer. You can also get a text version using SQL. Have a read of [this oracle-base article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/real-time-sql-monitoring-11gr1.php) for more details on using the SQL monitor.

It's possible that the reason for the differences is because the SQL is flipping between two execution plans. You can spot this by looking in the AWR to see this. To do this you'll need to find the sql_id for the statement(s) that are causing you issues. You can do this with:

```
select sql_id
from   v$sql
where  sql_text like '%your query here%'
and    sql_text not like '%not this%';
```

To find if there's changes, have a read of Kerry Osborne's [unstable plans](http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/2008/10/unstable-plans/) article and look for the "awr_plan_change" script.

If you are switching between plans, you can force it to keep the good plan using SQL profiles. Again, Kerry Osborne has a detailed [article on this](http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/2009/04/oracle-sql-profiles/).

Note that it's possible that the SQL you're interested in isn't stored in the AWR, as only the worst performing statements are kept. We can force details of it to be kept by "coloring" it however, as [discussed by Dion Cho](http://dioncho.wordpress.com/tag/colored-sql/).

Answer (score 1):

I would find the long running execution and then see what it is doing in ASH. ASH can be used to find the longest execution.  To find the longest execution run

```
 set linesize 150

 define v_dbid=NULL;
 select &v_dbid from dual;
 col f_dbid new_value v_dbid
 select &database_id f_dbid from dual;
 select &v_dbid from dual;
 select nvl(&v_dbid,dbid) f_dbid from v$database;
 select &v_dbid from dual;

 col 1 for 99999
 col 2 for 99999
 col 3 for 9999
 col 4 for 999
 col 5 for 99
 col av for 99999
 col ct for 99999
 col mn for 999
 col av for 99999.9
 col longest_sql_exec_id for A10
 col max_run_time for A35

 WITH pivot_data AS (
 SELECT
       sql_id,
       ct,
       mxdelta mx,
       mndelta mn,
       round(avdelta) av,
       WIDTH_BUCKET(delta_in_seconds,mndelta,mxdelta+.1,5) AS bucket  ,
       SUBSTR(times,12) max_run_time,
       SUBSTR(longest_sql_exec_id, 12) longest_sql_exec_id
 FROM (
 SELECT
    sql_id,
    delta_in_seconds,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sql_id) ct,
    MAX(delta_in_seconds) OVER (PARTITION BY sql_id) mxdelta,
    MIN(delta_in_seconds) OVER (PARTITION BY sql_id) mndelta,
    AVG(delta_in_seconds) OVER (PARTITION BY sql_id) avdelta,
    MAX(times) OVER (PARTITION BY sql_id) times,
    MAX(longest_sql_exec_id) OVER (PARTITION BY sql_id) longest_sql_exec_id
 FROM (
    SELECT
         sql_id,
         sql_exec_id,
         MAX(delta_in_seconds) delta_in_seconds ,
         LPAD(ROUND(MAX(delta_in_seconds),0),10) || ' ' ||
         TO_CHAR(MIN(start_time),'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  || ' ' ||
         TO_CHAR(MAX(end_time),'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  times,
         LPAD(ROUND(MAX(delta_in_seconds),0),10) || ' ' ||
         TO_CHAR(MAX(sql_exec_id)) longest_sql_exec_id
    FROM ( SELECT
                                             sql_id,
                                             sql_exec_id,
               CAST(sample_time AS DATE)     end_time,
               CAST(sql_exec_start AS DATE)  start_time,
               ((CAST(sample_time    AS DATE)) -
                (CAST(sql_exec_start AS DATE))) * (3600*24) delta_in_seconds
            FROM
               dba_hist_active_sess_history
            WHERE sql_exec_id IS NOT NULL
              and dbid=&v_dbid
         )
    GROUP BY sql_id,sql_exec_id
 )
 )
 where ct > &min_repeat_executions_filter
  and  mxdelta > &min_elapsed_time
 )
 SELECT * FROM pivot_data
 PIVOT ( COUNT(*) FOR bucket IN (1,2,3,4,5))
 ORDER BY mx DESC,av DESC
 ;
```

output will look like

```
  SQL_ID            CT         MX   MN       AV MAX_RUN_TIME                        LONGEST_SQ      1      2     3    4   5
  ------------- ------ ---------- ---- -------- ----------------------------------- ---------- ------ ------ ----- ---- ---
  2spgk3k0f7quz    251      29607    0    546.0 11-04-12 12:11:47 11-04-12 20:25:14 16781748      247      2     0    0   2
  990m08w8xav7s    591       7681    0     52.0 11-04-13 00:39:27 11-04-13 02:47:28 16786685      587      0     0    2   2
  64dqhdkkw63fd   1083       7147    0      7.0 11-03-07 04:01:01 11-03-07 06:00:08 16777218     1082      0     0    0   1
  0bujgc94rg3fj    604       4929    0     25.0 11-04-08 10:53:34 11-04-08 12:15:43 16814628      601      1     1    0   1
  0hbv80w9ypy0n    161       4089    0   1184.0 11-03-02 04:36:10 11-04-12 23:34:18 16777290       27    116     9    6   3
  bzyny95313u12    114       2599    0     47.0 11-03-03 03:06:18 11-03-03 03:49:37 16781191      113      0     0    0   1
  ds8cz0fb8w147    161       2531   13    274.0 11-03-01 23:11:48 11-04-12 16:10:37 16777285      136     18     5    1   1
  5k7vccwjr5ahd   2653       1963    0     33.0 11-03-01 23:10:12 11-04-12 09:06:12 16778244     2623     15     8    4   3
  4d6m2q3ngjcv9    320       1701    3    485.0 11-03-01 23:10:53 11-04-10 18:01:26 16777261       92    168    50    9   1
  g5u58zpg0tuk8     97       1359    1     62.0 11-04-12 02:23:37 11-04-13 02:51:09 16777217       92      3     1    0   1
  34cgtc9xkgxny     61       1272  978   1163.0 11-03-02 10:06:24 11-03-02 10:27:36 16777250        4      4    14
```

find the query you want. The SQL_ID can be translated into the SQL TEXT as Chris Saxon pointed out here. Once you have your query, get the "LONGEST_SQ" which is the sql_exec_id for the longest execution of that query. You can then go into ASH and get all the activity for that query, for example if my sql_exec_id is 16777217, then

```
  Select
  decode(session_state,'ON CPU','ON CPU’, event)
  From
        v$active_session_history
  Where
       sql_exec_id = 16777217
  Order by sample_id
```

and the output will look like

```
  DECODE(SESSION_STATE,'ONCPU','ONCPU',EVENT)
  ------------------------------------------------
  db file parallel read
  db file sequential read
  ON CPU
  ON CPU
  ON CPU
  ON CPU
```

This can be extended to include where in the execution plan the execution is spending time by adding those columns to the above query which are available starting in 11g.
This will give you and idea of where the query is spending it's time, like I/O, CPU, locks, or other stuff, but then the question is why? first thing to check is how many distinct execution plans the query has and see if fast and slow execution times relate to the plan. Chris Saxon has given links to finding the different execution plans.

More info on the method outlined here at http://www.oraclerealworld.com/finding-the-slowest-sql-execution-of-the-same-query/

If the plans are indeed the same, and the cursor activity doesn't point out anything strange like locks or such, then you probably want to check the bind variables. There is no reliable way to get bind variables other than tracing, but you can look at some example values using this method http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/bind-capture/
like

```
  variable x varchar2(10);
  exec :x:='X';
  col f_sqlid new_value v_sqlid
  col f_sqlcn new_value v_sqlcn
  col f_binddata new_value v_binddata
  select * from dual where dummy=:x;
  select
  PREV_SQL_ID f_sqlid,
  PREV_CHILD_NUMBER f_sqlcn
  from v$session
  where sid = ( Select sid from v$mystat where rownum=1 ) ;
  select bind_data f_binddata from v$sql
  where sql_id = '&v_sqlid'
  and child_number = &v_sqlcn
  /
  SELECT * FROM TABLE ( DBMS_SQLTUNE.EXTRACT_BINDS ( '&v_binddata' )) ;
  SELECT xmltype(other_xml) AS xmlval
  FROM v$sql_plan
  WHERE
  sql_id = '&v_sqlid' AND
  child_number = &v_sqlcn AND
  other_xml IS NOT NULL
  /
```

PS this is pretty far out but you can trace, starting on 11, the execution of a particular SQL_ID across all users.

Example

```
  SQL> alter session set events 'sql_trace [707wu2umpfas7],wait=true,bind=true';
```

see http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2010/06/23/the-full-power-of-oracles-diagnostic-events-part-2-oradebug-doc-and-11g-improvements/